# How can i send a file attachment in discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to be able to let the user send a file, then i will do stuff with the text and send a message with the changed text as an attachment.

I got the text using this

```
request(url, {json: false}, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) {return msg.reply("There was an error getting the file")}
})
```

but I do not know how I can send a file attachment

Comment: You can just do `msg.reply("Something", { files: ["./file.txt"] })` to send a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example:

```
await msg.reply({
    content:
        `Text`,
    files: ["path to file"]
}).catch((err) => {
     console.log("Error during Export File " + err);
});;
```